# Databinding list of objects to a data grid view

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have this manual adding of data or row in the grid and I would like to ask some idea on how to implement data binding in vb.net.

```
memberGrid.Rows.Clear()

For Each m As Member In members
    Dim row As Object() = {m.MemberId, EntityHelper.FullName(m.Person.FirstName, m.Person.SurName),
                                   WorkoutLogic.GetLastWorkoutDateDisplay(m.MemberId, AppRuntime.Workouts),
                                   LogicService.GetMembershipStatus(m.MembershipHistories),
                                    m.Person.Mobile}
    memberGrid.Rows.Add(row)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
memberGrid.DataSource = (From m In members
                         Select New With { Id = m.MemberId,
                                           FullName = EntityHelper.FullName(m.Person.FirstName, m.Person.SurName),
                                           LastWorkout = WorkoutLogic.GetLastWorkoutDateDisplay(m.MemberId, AppRuntime.Workouts), 
                                           Status = LogicService.GetMembershipStatus(m.MembershipHistories), 
                                           Mobile = m.Person.Mobile }).ToList()
```

Change the names before the `=`'s to match the names of your columns.

Comment: Is this the one I will replace to above codes? Is this code will automatically add the items to the grid?

Comment: Yes. It will also add the columns if you don't have columns with those names.